# Many-to-many in OOP: Class A instantiates Class B, which instantiates Class A, which

Tags: php, object-oriented, orm

I am mapping Field1 to Field2. The map object instantiates the field object and vice versa, creating an infinite loop.

This is in PHP.

```
class field {
  protected $maps; // mapCollection object. all the mappings of this field to others

}

class map {
  protected $field1; // field object
  protected $field2; // field object
}

class mapCollection {
  protected $maps; // array of map objects
}
```

The mappings and fieldsets are stored in a database where they each have a unique ID. So I decided to allow fetching them using their ids in the constructors.

```
class field {
  protected $maps; // map object
  public __construct($id = 0 ) {
    if(!empty($id) ) {
      $this->maps = // get mapsCollection. data from db
    }
  }

}

class map {
  protected $field1; // field object
  protected $field2; // field object
  public __construct($id = 0 ) {
    if(!empty($id) ) {
      $this->field1 = // get field1 data from db
      $this->field2 = // get field2 data from db
    }
  }
}

class mapCollection {
  protected $maps; // array of map objects
  public __construct($field_id) {
    // get maps from db by field id
    foreach($dbdata as $map_id) {
      $this->maps[] = new map($map_id); // instantiates new map, which instantiates new field, etc
    }
  }
}
```

How should I be doing this?

Comment: How about "don't use ORM".

Comment: @teresko I have a mysql database. I have to access it somehow, right?

Comment: Sure. Write a [data mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html). **You do not need ORM to assess MySQL**. Unless, of course, you cannot write any SQL.

Comment: @teresko: What do you have against ORM's?  :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey http://stackoverflow.com/a/7767323/1208233

Comment: @teresko: Hmm, that data mapper you linked looks suspiciously like an ORM to me.  Some ORM's are just data mapper classes that have been code-genned from the table schemas.  Why, when I was your age...

Comment: If all you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I think you're confusing. DataMapper is a more generalized implementation of ORM. It abstracts the need for your objects to match your storage schema.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Ah, you mean like Entity Framework.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The idea of a DataMapper is to completely separate your logic from your storage and from the logic of fetching/saving from/to storage. You could say it's like an Entity Framework, although that still wouldn't be quite accurate. Check out teresko's top answer on [so] for a better explanation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey entity framework is just an example of such an ORM. What ORMs do is create a 1 to 1 mapping of your DB schema (a big portion of it at least) and let you work with what appears to be a database of objects. Like Madera said, it's a matching. DataMapper just means you match an object in memory to your database in _some abstracted way_, it's independent of your DB structure usually.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Is there a real-world example of software implementing this pattern?  Is there a generalized DataMapper library?  Isn't that just a Generic Repository?  I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I don't find teresko's answer compelling.  It does a lot of hand-waving about exponential complexity and performance problems, but doesn't seem to talk about Data Mapper at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey of course... most of my code that works with a database does this one way or the other. If you have a `class Book` in your code that contains information that's sometimes from a table, sometimes from the web and sometimes from a join on two tables, it's an example of a data mapper since the source of the data is not tightly coupled to a specific DB table.. Really, most code that doesn't use an ORM (and a lot that does) uses a DataMapper one way or another...

Comment: @RobertHarvey Repository is closely related but completely different. The repository represents how the collection data might be queried where the data mapper is in charge of how it's fetched from the DB, it's a one layer difference usually. In the .NET world,ORMs like EntityFramework utilize language tools like LINQ to create a nice abstraction over the concept of querying the database, but again, you have a 1-1 link to the tables, so it's neither a data mapper or a repository really, it kind of takes the role of both which sometimes works well and sometimes fails miserably.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: EF doesn't require a 1:1 mapping.  There's a translation layer in the middle you can use.  I'm not clear on what you meant by "some abstracted way."

Comment: @RobertHarvey If you use stuff like entity splitting and such in EF, I _guess_ you can kind of make it do what a data mapper would do and kind of what a repository would do. You still have one thing that does the job of several others which is an interesting compromise. Remember, most languages don't have capabilities like LINQ or breaking code expressions up and processing them with LINQ adapters. Think about how you would perform these tasks without a language provided IQueryable interface and common implementations.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Thanks. Now I'm starting to get it.

Answer (score 4):

It is called a circular dependency.  Typically the way you resolve them is you have an unbiased third party create both A and B then introduce them to one another.  This should break the infinite loop and allow things to progress.

Another option is give both your field and map class a constructor that takes the other object as a parameter.  Now only load from the database if you don't get what you are looking for passed in.

Comment: I'm thinking perhaps my third-party would use the "builder pattern." I guess I'll not have the circular dependencies in the constructor. The builder will (somehow?) know which objects to create and then throw them together. Voila. I'm new to design patterns. But my application is getting too complex for me to just keep hacking away at it without a grander scheme.